parameterzing sizes of fames
Continuing!
Can I get some help, parameterizing the sizes of the frames for each column ... need a way to tweak these some text lines up perfectly! I suppose if I use the two columns of frames then the sizes will be relative to each other based on page size and margins  ...
See earlier question: Alternating pages.
I would like:

before the bordered columns have normal single column text ...for a few pages
use the UNNMUMBERED section names in the page header ...
use fancy drop caps for first letter in each section

... AND (!) a border page with some art
More info:
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
% ateb: % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726457/
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=2cm,
  outer=10cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylightGray}{rgb}{41,84,231}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength\mlinessep
\newlength\mlinesmargin
\newsavebox\mframetxtbox
\newsavebox\mframedotsbox
\newif\ifmframetxt
\newif\ifmframedots
\AddToHook{begindocument}
{%
  \newlength\mlinelength
  \setlength\mlinelength{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+2.54cm-\mlinesmargin-\columnsep}%
  \newlength\mlinesdrop
  \setlength\mlinesdrop{\dimexpr\topmargin+\headheight+2.54cm+\headsep+\textheight}%
  \newlength\mlinesoddindent
  \setlength\mlinesoddindent{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+2.54cm+\textwidth+\columnsep}%
  \newlength\mframedrop
  \setlength\mframedrop{\dimexpr\mlinesdrop-0.5\textheight}%
  \newlength\mframetxtoddindent
  \newlength\mframetxtevenindent
  \setlength\mframetxtevenindent{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+2.54cm+0.5\textwidth}%
  \setlength\mframetxtoddindent{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+2.54cm+0.5\textwidth}%
  \newlength\mframedotsoddindent
  \newlength\mframedotsevenindent
  \setlength\mframedotsevenindent{\dimexpr\mlinesmargin+0.5\mlinelength}%
  \setlength\mframedotsoddindent{\dimexpr\mlinesoddindent+0.5\mlinelength}%
  \newsavebox\mline
  \newcounter{mlinecount}%
  \edef\tempa{\fpeval{\textheight/\mlinessep}}%
  \def\mkint#1.#2nil{#1}%
  \edef\tempb{\expandafter\mkint\tempa.#2nil}%
  \setcounter{mlinecount}{\tempb}%
  \sbox\mline{%
    \hbox to \mlinelength {%
      \leaders \hbox to 0.333em {\hss \textcolor{mlinescol}{.}\hss} \hfill \kern 0pt
    }%
  }%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}
  {%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \multiput(\mlinesoddindent,-\mlinesdrop)(0,\mlinessep){\themlinecount}{\usebox\mline}%
      \ifmframetxt
        \put(\mframetxtoddindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframetxtbox}%
      \fi
      \ifmframedots
        \put(\mframedotsoddindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframedotsbox}%
      \fi
    \else
      \multiput(\mlinesmargin,-\mlinesdrop)(0,\mlinessep){\themlinecount}{\usebox\mline}%
      \ifmframetxt
        \put(\mframetxtevenindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframetxtbox}%
      \fi
      \ifmframedots
        \put(\mframedotsevenindent,-\mframedrop){\usebox\mframedotsbox}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
% kernel drawing is either 'highly experimental' or produces poor quality results for rounded corners, so use tikz for frames
% to avoid needless overhead, draw the frame only once
\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \sbox\mframetxtbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded corners,text width=\textwidth,text height=\textheight,text depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \sbox\mframedotsbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),overlay]
      \node (mframe) [draw=mframecol,rounded corners,text width=\mlinelength,text height=\textheight,text depth=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
% configuration
% the distance between dotted lines
\setlength\mlinessep{0.2in}
% the distance between the edge of the paper and the dotted lines
\setlength\mlinesmargin{\columnsep}
% frame colour
\colorlet{mframecol}{blue}
% dot colour
\colorlet{mlinescol}{gray}
% frame text?
\mframetxttrue
% \mframetxtfalse
% frame dots?
\mframedotstrue
% \mframetxtfalse


\hyphenation{BAB-Y-LON hea-ven hun-dred mir-a-cles MY-STER-Y Per-gam-os Phil-a-del-Phi-a pro-phe-sy pro-phet-ess pre-pared pow-er them-selves thou-sand three-score thun-der-ings voi-ces}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{8pt}

\begin{document}


\Large


\input{Bible/Revelation/Revelation01}


\end{document}


AND

\section*{Revelation 1} 

The  Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God  gave unto him, to shew unto his servants things which must shortly come to pass; and he  sent and  signified \emph{it} by his angel unto his servant John:

\noindent [2] Who bare record of the word of God, and of the  testimony of Jesus Christ, and of all things that he saw.

\noindent [3] Blessed \emph{is} he that readeth, and they that hear the words of this prophecy, and keep those things which are written therein: for the time \emph{is} at hand.

\noindent [4] John to the seven churches which are in Asia: Grace \emph{be} unto you, and peace, from him which is, and which was, and which is to come; and from the seven Spirits which are before his throne;

\noindent [5] And from Jesus Christ, \emph{who} \emph{is} the faithful witness, \emph{and} the first begotten of the dead, and the prince of the kings of the earth. Unto him that loved us, and washed us from our sins in his own blood,

\noindent [6] And hath  made us kings and priests unto God and his Father; to him \emph{be} glory and dominion for ever and ever. Amen.

\noindent [7] Behold, he cometh with clouds; and  every eye shall see him, and they \emph{also} which pierced him: and all kindreds of the earth shall wail  because of him. Even so, Amen.

\noindent [8] I am  Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending,  saith the Lord, which is, and which was, and which is to come, the Almighty.

\noindent [9] I John, who also am your brother, and companion in tribulation, and in the kingdom and patience of Jesus Christ, was in the isle that is called Patmos, for the word of God, and for the testimony of Jesus Christ.

\noindent [10] I was in the Spirit on the Lord's day, and heard behind me a great voice, as of a trumpet,

\noindent [11] Saying, I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last: and, What thou seest, write in a book, and send \emph{it} unto the seven churches which are in Asia; unto Ephesus, and unto Smyrna, and unto Pergamos, and unto Thyatira, and unto Sardis, and unto Philadelphia, and unto Laodicea.

\noindent [12] And I turned to see the voice that spake with me. And being turned, I saw seven golden candlesticks;

\noindent [13] And in the midst of the seven candlesticks \emph{one} like unto the Son of man, clothed with a garment down to the foot, and girt about the paps with a golden girdle.

\noindent [14] His head and \emph{his} hairs \emph{were} white like wool, as white as snow; and his eyes \emph{were} as a flame of fire;

\noindent [15] And his feet like unto fine brass, as if they burned in a furnace; and his voice as the sound of many waters.

\noindent [16] And he had in his right hand seven stars: and out of his mouth went a sharp  twoedged sword: and his countenance \emph{was} as the sun shineth in his strength.

\noindent [17] And when I saw him, I fell at his feet as dead. And he laid his right hand upon me, saying unto me, Fear not; I am the first and the last:

\noindent [18] I \emph{am} he that liveth, and was dead; and, behold, I am alive for evermore, Amen; and have the keys of hell and of death.

\noindent [19] Write the things which thou hast seen, and the things which are, and the things which shall be hereafter;

\noindent [20] The mystery of the seven stars which thou sawest in my right hand, and the seven golden candlesticks. The seven stars are the angels of the seven churches: and the seven candlesticks which thou sawest are the seven churches.


it's generally better to abide by the one-question-per-question rule because it keeps things focused and increases your chances of getting answers. so I suggest splitting this question into 3 or 4 separate ones. however, I have no idea what the part after the 'ANDis asking for. for question (3) seelettrine`.

also, please could you correct your code so we can compile it?

I'd be happy to address each of these once I figure out how to ... this code was an answer to earlier questions ...and I'm new to this area of Latex ... thanks  ... more to follow ... General question is created a document that has a frame of text on inside half of pages and a frame with dotted lines for outside half ... would like to parameterize the geometry for some fine tuning/tweaking ...

what I mean is, you should ask each of your 4 questions as a separate question. so edit this one to ask one thing e.g. just (1). then ask another question about (2), another about (3) and another about the 'AND' bit. but nobody but you can compile your code because we don't have Bible/Revelation/Revelation01.tex. is the stuff after \end{document} the content of that file? if so, just replace your \input{} with that content in the example.
